# Having Trouble Updating Database Table in C# LINQ ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have some code here trying to update two tables in my SQL database.  The first 9 lines are working fine. Retrieving an order using the order id and updating the order date, status, etc..  you'll notice the one additional line where I am fetching the discount code used during the checkout and this is working fine as well.  However, the 2nd chunk of code is supposed to query the Discounts table and update the record that matches the discount code used during checkout.  For some reason, PaidOrderDiscount is resulting in null.  I've debugged it in Visual Studio and confirmed that PaidOrderDiscCode is valid and it does match one record's DiscCode field in the discounts table.  Not sure why this is returning a null result but as a consequence, the code is not updating the use count field.  Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

```cs
var PaidOrder =
    applicationDbContext
        .Orders
        .Where(i => i.OrdId == updateOrderRequest.OrdId)
        .FirstOrDefault();

var PaidOrderDiscCode = "";

if (PaidOrder != null)
{
    PaidOrderDiscCode = PaidOrder.DiscCode;
    PaidOrder.OrdDate = DateTime.Now;
    PaidOrder.OrdStatus = "Paid";
    PaidOrder.PmtId = updateOrderRequest.PmtId;
    applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();

    if (PaidOrderDiscCode != "")
    {
        var PaidOrderDiscount =
            applicationDbContext
                .Discounts
                .Where(i => i.DiscCode == PaidOrderDiscCode)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (PaidOrderDiscount != null)
        {
            PaidOrderDiscount.DiscUsecount = 1;
            applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe there is a white space or a capital letter which cause this condtion be always false `i.DiscCode == PaidOrderDiscCode`, normalize(lowercase, trim white spaces) both sides and try the condition,

Comment: @Todd Wunsch, based on my test, there is no problem about your code. If the data is matched, the code will update the database. Therefore, it is best for you to check if their value is the same.

Comment: i.DiscCode.Trim().ToUpper() == PaidOrderDiscCode.Trim().ToUpper()
or use string.Compare: (string.Compare("a", "A", true) == 0)

Comment: First thing to do is add a navigation property `Order.Discount`. Then it's trivial to update an Order and its `Discount` in one operation.